# I want to set a transparent background layer when I click on the floating action menu.

Tags: android, xml, layout, material-design

This is what I have done so far. Created FloatingActionButton. Now As the + icon is pressed a translucent layer should be there at the back.

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
 <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu
                android:id="@+id/actionMenu"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
                fab:fab_addButtonColorNormal="@color/primary"
                fab:fab_addButtonColorPressed="@color/primary_dark"
                fab:fab_addButtonPlusIconColor="#ffffff">

                <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:onClick="openAudio"
                    fab:fab_colorNormal="#EA1E63"
                    fab:fab_colorPressed="#EA1E63"
                    fab:fab_icon="@drawable/ic_action_mic" />
 </com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu>

</RelativeLayout
```

Comment: I've tried. That's not working well

Comment: sorry this was wrong answer so i have remove my answer for your case

Comment: ok. Can u suggest anything else?

Comment: there are lot of peoples who will help you if they know solution for your queries....

Comment: were you able to find solution for this ?  I am stuck with the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
floatingActionMenuButton.setOnMenuToggleListener(new FloatingActionMenu.OnMenuToggleListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMenuToggle(boolean opened) {
                if (opened) {
                    //menu opened
                } else {
                    //menu closed
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

use setBackgroundResource or setBackgroundColor. I think first is pretty simple.

Second one takes an int as an argument. So, just convert your hex color (for example #55000000) into decimal and it will work as well.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and i fixed it in following way.

I added a relative layout which will match parent in both width and height.
Set its background color to black and set alpha to your required opacity.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/obstructor"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:alpha="0.75"
    android:background="@android:color/black">

</RelativeLayout>
```

And then on the menu item expanded and collapsed make this visible and invisible.

```
mFabMenu = (FloatingActionsMenu) findViewById(R.id.multiple_actions);
final RelativeLayout obstrucuterView = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.obstructor);
obstrucuterView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (obstrucuterView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
            mFabMenu.collapse();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});

mFabMenu.setOnFloatingActionsMenuUpdateListener(new FloatingActionsMenu.OnFloatingActionsMenuUpdateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onMenuExpanded() {
        if (obstrucuterView.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE)
            obstrucuterView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMenuCollapsed() {
        if (obstrucuterView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
            obstrucuterView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Good to know Sourav.. :)

Answer (score 0):

There is another custom library which is more advanced than what you are using right now.

**Get it here**
[Clans floating Action Button](https://github.com/Clans/FloatingActionButton/%22Clans%20Floating%20Action%20Button%22)

Set this to true and it will solve your problem. Do let me know if it helps

```
fabPlusButton.setClosedOnTouchOutside(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [Clans floating Action Button](https://github.com/Clans/FloatingActionButton/%22Clans%20Floating%20Action%20Button%22) then perhaps `fab:menu_backgroundColor` might be something that you could have a look at if it satisfies your use-case. ofcourse the layout width and height should both match parent (This solution has worked for me)