# I am trying to figure out how to add dim background on click of FAB menu present in Navigational drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, floating-action-button

I have FAB menu in navigation drawer. I m using android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton button and onclick of this we show four FAB in arc shape. I have a container in Navigation drawer  which keep replacing the fragment in the drawer(normal behaviour of the drawer). How can i disable the background when user click on FAB menu button. I'm a little stuck on how to complete this though.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


 <FrameLayout
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"
        >
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/obstructor"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:alpha="1000"
            android:background="@android:color/black">
</RelativeLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/home"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/frame_container"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_navigation_close_inverted"
        app:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        app:rippleColor="#F06292">
</android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton>
    </FrameLayout>
   </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not set it by setting a flag you need to add a dummy layout for the back portion of the FAB buttons and make it clickable when FAB is clicked

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


 <FrameLayout
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"
        >
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/obstructor"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:alpha="1000"
            android:background="@android:color/black">
</RelativeLayout>
 <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/llRoot"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:clickable="false"
    android:orientation="vertical" />
        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/home"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/frame_container"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_navigation_close_inverted"
        app:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        app:rippleColor="#F06292">
</android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton>
    </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: I tried with a dummy background and sets its alpha as 0.75f but the background is not visible. I think due to the other fragment present in the drawer

Comment: Can you post your xml?

Comment: Added ll_root make it clickable when FAB is Clicked

Comment: i made it but still not visible :(

Comment: its coming below the fragment seems opacity is somehow not working here. i event set focusability but still view is coming in background of the fragment

Comment: You need to set background for the ll_root .Don't use any other thing

Comment: I set the background as well but now working. Is this due to the drawer fragment replace issues which does something to override ll root layout. click on layout also not working even when i m making it clickable

Comment: As frame_container is being replace in each fragment, ll_root  alpha is not working as well as i can see expandable listviews are present in each fragment of drawer is which is causing trouble in View. Still ll layout is coming in background of fragment due to Framelayout of navigation drawer

Comment: I have try this solution also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30432997/i-want-to-set-a-transparent-background-layer-when-i-click-on-the-floating-action/30911071#30911071 but when i make call      getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, new MyFragment()).commit(); the dummy/blur background is coming behind of the fragment rather than on top of fragment

Comment: I resolved this issue by using  android:translationZ="2dp"

Answer (score 1):

Add this in your layout,

> ```
>             android:translationZ="2dp"
> ```

it will work

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/obstructor"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:alpha="0.75"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:translationZ="2dp"

            />
```